# How to redirect Incorrect login details used with wp_login_url?

Tags: php, wordpress

I've come across the [wp_login_url](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_url) function on wordpress - this has been useful whilst styling a front end login form to allow users access restricted frontend site content.

However if a user incorrectly enters their details - they are kicked out to the /wp-login.php form instead.

How can a user be redirected to the front end form I've created when an error like this occurs?

Cheers

Comment: take a look at the login_url() function -> http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
if (isset($_GET['failed_login'])) {
    $extra = "style = \"color: red;\"";
    $warning = "Username or Password did not match!";
}
```